# Open GL and Canvas which method is more suitable for making custome brushes in drawing application?

Tags: android

I want to make brushes displayed in below image for drawing application. Which is a suitable method - Open GL or Canvas & How can we implement it? 
[image]

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Canvas, as you'll want to modify an image. OpenGLES is good for displaying images, but does not (as far as I know) have methods for modifying its textures (unless you render to a texture that then render to screen with some modifications, which is not always so effective).

Using the Canvas you will have the methods for drawing your brush-strokes onto the Bitmap you're painting on, in GLES you would have to modify a texture (by using a canvas) and then upload that to the GPU again, before it could be rendered, and the rendering would most likely just consist of drawing a square with your texture on it (as the fillrate for most mobile GPUs are quite bad, you don't want to draw the strokes separately).

What I'm trying to say is; *The most convenient way to let the user draw on an openGLES surface would be by creating a texture by drawing on a Canvas*.
But, there might still be some gain in using GL for drawing, as the Canvas-operations can be performed off-screen, and you can push this data to a gl-renderer to (possibly) speed up the on-screen drawing.

*However*; if you are developing for Android 3.x+ you should take a look at [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html), (which I personally have never had a chance to use), but seems like it would be a good solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution is going to be using native code. That's how Sketchbook does it. You could probably figure out how by browsing through the GIMP source code http://www.gimp.org/source . Out of Canvas vs OpenGL, Canvas would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. if you want to edit the image statically, go with canvas. But if you want after brushing the screen, to have the ability to edit, scale, rotate, it would be easier with opengl.

An example with opengl: Store the motion the user do with touchs. create a class that store a motion and have fields for size, rotation etc. to draw this class, just make a path of the brush image selected following the stored motion.